# Youtube videos frame not appear or play in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, youtube

I have an issue with an existing app, the issue is that app plays a Youtube videos within the app in a UIScrollView but after I have installed the new Xcode SDK 4.5.2 these videos have a blank white square and they are not working like they used to when I tap on them,here is the code I have in my app :

```
- (void)playVideo:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame
{
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width,        frame.size.height];
UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];


[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
[self.scrollView addSubview:videoView];
[videoView release];
NSLog(@"%@",html);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[self playVideo:@"http://www.youtube.com/...." frame:CGRectMake(5, 20, 110, 110)];

[self playVideo:@"http://www.youtube.com/...." frame:CGRectMake(5, 170, 110, 110)];

[self playVideo:@"http://www.youtube.com/...." frame:CGRectMake(5, 320, 110, 110)];

[self playVideo:@"http://www.youtube.com/...." frame:CGRectMake(5, 470, 110, 110)];

[self playVideo:@"http://www.youtube.com/...." frame:CGRectMake(5, 620, 110, 110)];

[self playVideo:@"http://www.youtube.com/...." frame:CGRectMake(5, 765, 110, 110)];


[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1400)];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I don't know what I need to change in this code to make them appear and play again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my issue. The only thing I need to change in my code was to replace this code:

```
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";
```

with this code:

```
NSString *embedHTML = @"<body style=\"margin:0\"> <iframe height=\"110\" width=\"110\"        src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/HERE YOU PUT THE ID OF YOUR VIDEO\"   frameborder=\"0\"/></iframe></body> ";
```